# Java program not accumulating correctly

Tags: java

So when I run this code, it just puts 1 on each of my variables then ends. It's not accumulating my total coins correctly. It doesn't seem my while loops aren't actually looping, it just adds one to the total then goes to the next while. I'm really confused on what's going on so any help is appreciated!

Here is a link to what it looks like after running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6MIC.jpg

```
package MinumumCoins;

public class MinimumCoins
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  System.out.println("Please enter amount of change (1-99)");
  System.out.println("");

 Keyboard kbd;
 kbd= new Keyboard();

 int totQuarters = 0;
 int totDimes = 0;
 int totNickles = 0;
 int totPennies = 0;
 int Amount = kbd.readInt();



   while (Amount>=25)

       Amount=Amount-25;

           totQuarters=totQuarters+1;



   while (Amount>=10)

       Amount=Amount-10;

               totDimes=totDimes+1;



    while (Amount>=5)

        Amount=Amount-5;

                totNickles=totNickles+1;



    while (Amount>=1)

        Amount=Amount-1;

            totPennies=totPennies+1;

   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Quarters: "+totQuarters);
   System.out.println("Dimes: "+totDimes);
   System.out.println("Nickles: "+totNickles);
   System.out.println("Pennies: "+totPennies);





  } //end of main string

} //end of class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose statements in blocks by surrounding them with brackets `{}`, otherwise only the first line will get executed in the loop:

This:

```
 while (Amount>=25) 
           Amount=Amount-25;    
           totQuarters=totQuarters+1;
```

will be executed as:

```
while (Amount>=25)    
   Amount=Amount-25;       // this is in the loop.
totQuarters=totQuarters+1; // this is not in the loop.
```

Do this instead:

```
while (Amount>=25) {    
       Amount=Amount-25;    
       totQuarters=totQuarters+1;
}
```

Change this for all the while-loops.

Also, if you want to save space a statement on the form `amount = amount - 25` can be rewritten with the *Compound Assignment Operator* as `amount -= 25` and a statement on the form `totQuarters=totQuarters+1` can be written as `totQuarters++` using the *postfix increment operator* or as `++totQuarters` using the *prefix increment operator*.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked! Thanks for the operator tip as well!

Answer (score 0):

Add { } to your loops. Else it will only be running once, as it only runs the first line.

Ex.

```
while (Amount>=25) {
   Amount=Amount-25;
   totQuarters=totQuarters+1;
}

while (Amount>=10) {
   Amount=Amount-10;
   totDimes=totDimes+1;
}

while (Amount>=5) {
   Amount=Amount-5;
   totNickles=totNickles+1;
}

while (Amount>=1) {
    Amount=Amount-1;
    totPennies=totPennies+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing, I'll make sure not to make that bracket mistake again!